# Does normalising a vector cancel a scaling operation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a vector `X = (4, 12)`, a [normalisation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) `u`, and a constant `C`, does `u(X) = u(CX)`. If so could someone provide some intuition as to why that is?

**Update:** my question was not well formulated, `u(X) = u(CX)` could mean many things, but what I had in mind was, do `x1 = x'1`, and `x2 = x'2` where `X'` is the scaled normalised vector and while `X` is the non scaled normalised vector

Comment: I could not find the definition of $u$ in your link. Tell us what $u$ is.

Comment: If $u(X)=\frac  X {\|X\|}$ then the equation $u(X)=u(CX)$ is true for $c \geq 0$.

Comment: Indeed that's what the definition of `u` was. Thanks for the insights

Comment: Well. I guess your normalisation function does something like $x \mapsto\lVert x\rVert ^{-1} x$. Then it only acts on the vector space without the null vector, so your definitely not allowed to scale by $c=0$. If your field are the reals, then $u(cx)$ is $x$ or $-x$. In case of complex numbers, you can get an (any) additional phase.

Comment: Sorry my question is not well formulated, i've updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x = (4,12)$ and we have some scalar $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Then the normalisation of $x$ and $cx = (4c,12c)$ looks like
\begin{align} \frac{x}{\|x\|} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4^2+12^2}}(4,12) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{160}}(4,12) \\ \frac{cx}{\|cx\|} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(4c)^2+(12c)^2}}(4c,12c) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{160 c^2}}(4c,12c).
\end{align}
Taking $c^2$ out of the square root ($\sqrt{c^2} = |c|$) we obtain
\begin{equation}
\frac{cx}{\|cx\|} = \frac{c}{|c|}\frac{1}{\sqrt{160}}(4,12).
\end{equation}
Thus the two normalised vectors are the same other than the prefactor $\frac{c}{|c|}$. Note that if $c>0$ then $\frac{c}{|c|} = 1$ and if $c<0$ then $\frac{c}{|c|} = -1$. So if $c>0$ then the two normalisations are the same and if $c<0$ then 
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{\|x\|} = -\frac{cx}{\|cx\|}.
\end{equation}
So your premise is not always valid. This is because if $c<0$ then the "direction" of the vector changes and so this new normalised vector would point in the opposite direction. Furthermore, if $c = 0$ then $cx = (0,0)$ and this can't be normalised!

---

This can all be generalised for any vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$.